# Can we upgrade the flex builder 3 sdk?

Tags: apache-flex

currently i have installed flex builder 3 with the default sdk 3.0.  Now i want to upgrade flex sdk to 4.1.

is this possible or i have to purchase flex builder 4?

Answer (score 2):

You can download the 4.1 sdk from http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+4 and still use Flex Builder 3. Just add the sdk through your preferences -> Installed Flex SDKs.

For a detailed instruction, check this link: http://butterfliesandbugs.wordpress.com/2009/05/21/using-flex-builder-3-with-the-flex-4-sdk/

Comment: ok i already did this. try this sample code http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_SimpleAudioRecorder___Microphone_Access_API_AIR_2_-16746.html   Not able to compile it any idea why?

Comment: What is the problem? I don't have FB3 currently installed.

Comment: Bare in mind that some of the cookbooks code doesn't compile cause it contains compilation errors. Your Flex Builder shouldn't be the fault if you have the correct SDK set up and added. 
Good luck!

Comment: error is : unable to open 'D:\flex_sdk_4.1.0.16076_mpl\frameworks\libs\player\9.0\playerglobal.swc'

Comment: Are you able to create a new Flex project with SDK 4.1 successfully? If not, try putting the folder with the sdk where your other sdk files are. For example mine are in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\sdks" Then just add that folder through the Flex Builder preferences and try creating a new project again.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible to use 4 sdk in Flex Builder 3.

Comment: Yes you can. I've just tested it.

Comment: now i change sdk to 4.5.1 and after creating new project getting following error 'D:\flex_sdk_4.5.1.21328_mpl\frameworks\libs\player\9.0\playerglobal.swc'.

Comment: Why is it searching for flash player 9.0 ? It should be searching for 10.2. Can you set in the preferences of the project to use a specific flash player version and set it to 10.2.0 ?

Comment: @cupuyc 
http://butterfliesandbugs.wordpress.com/2009/05/21/using-flex-builder-3-with-the-flex-4-sdk/

Comment: @Anton Petrov But that was old gumbo. Thanks that you tested.

Comment: @Anton i think there are some problems in the flex sdk 1.4.1. when i tried with the sdk 1.4.5 its working. i put the sdk 1.4.5 in the following location "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\sdks" and change "Required Flex Player version" to 10-2-0. after these changes its working.

Answer (score 0):

Flex SDK 4.1 can be found here: http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flex/sdk/flex_sdk_4.1.zip